# Get screen on which application is running

Tags: c#, winapi, position

I want to detect on which screen a window is displayed when I got its handle. I found a `SetWindowPos()` function in Win API, but unfortunately there is no `GetWindowPos()` just a `GetWindowRect()`, but this results some odd values.

I got two devices, left one 1280x1024 and right one (primary) 1680x1050. When I want to get the position of a minimized firefox, I get b/l/r/t -31973/-32000/-31840/-32000 for either screen.

How do I know that it is my left or my right screen?

Comment: Or indeed, a window can span multiple screens...

Comment: Do not ask for the window position of a minimized window.  It is minimized, it doesn't have a position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinAPI has a [`MonitorFromRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which is probably what you need. I'm not sure if there's a C# equivalent, but you can call it through interop.

Be aware that the window can be on both monitors, or on neither. The API has flags for that, e.g. `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST`.

Comment: There's a managed API for this also.  Once he gets the window coordinates using `GetWindowPlacement`, it's not necessary to p/invoke anything to find what screen contains them.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`GetWindowPlacement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518.aspx), in order to find the rectangle that the window will use if it were restored.

Comment: @David: One certainly has to match those coordinates against the list of currently active screens.  It seems like UNeverNo is already planning to do this.

Comment: Whoops, I can't read, ignore what I said. (I thought he was getting odd results from a maximized window, not a minimized one.)